# How to optimize C++ avr code

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, avr, micro-optimization

To set or clear a bit in a register I use the following code:

```
template<int... pos, class Int>
static constexpr void write_one(Int& i)
{
    using expand = int[];
    expand{0,((i |= (Int{1} << pos)), 0)...};
}

template<int... pos, class Int>
static constexpr void write_zero(Int& i)
{
    using expand = int[];
    expand{0,((i &= ~(Int{1} << pos)), 0)...};
}
```

It works fine. To test its efficiency I write 2 test functions:

```
// The most efficiency
while(1){
    PORTB |= (1 << PB0);
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB0);
}

// This is the one I want to measure
while(1){
     Bit::write_one<PB0>(PORTB);
     Bit::write_zero<PB0>(PORTB);
}
```

When I measure times with an oscilloscope the second one takes more time, so I disassamble the code getting the following:

```
; This is the first one (of course, the most efficient)
000000c8 <_Z12testv>:
ce: 28 9a           sbi 0x05, 0 ; 5
d0: 28 98           cbi 0x05, 0 ; 5
d2: fd cf           rjmp    .-6         ; 0xce <_Z12testv+0x6>

; The second one
000000c8 <_Z12testv>:
; The compiler optimize perfectly write_one<PB0>(PORTB)
ce: 28 9a           sbi 0x05, 0 ; 5

; but, look what happens with write_zero<PB0>(PORTB)!!! 
; Why the compiler can't write "cbi"???
; Here is the problem:
d0: 85 b1           in  r24, 0x05   ; 5
d2: 90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
d4: 8e 7f           andi    r24, 0xFE   ; 254
d6: 85 b9           out 0x05, r24   ; 5

d8: fa cf           rjmp    .-12        ; 0xce <_Z12testv+0x6>
```

I'm using avr-g++ 4.9.2 with -O3 flag.

Comment: I don't really understand the assembler but might it be worth trying a pass by *value* and returning the new *value*? Passing by *reference* may be adding complications?

Comment: I don't even understand that C++ variant (I'm not that good in it, no idea what that expand does, and how it would work with other types than `Int = int`), but makes me wonder what you don't like about the simple first version of classic bit manipulation, where everything is clear. Maybe you get the compiler confused by it too, the gcc 4.9 was not that clever, and that's the base of avr-g++ I guess.

Comment: G++4.9.2 is not the worlds newest c++ compiler but on a x86-64 both compiles to the same code. (see https://godbolt.org/g/N6TgzU)

Comment: @Surt: With minor tweaks you can compile the code in Godbolt using "AVR gcc 4.6.4" and again the results are the same for both version.  I can't reproduce OP's issue.

Comment: The type of PORTB or BP0 might not be what we expect.

Comment: To be honest I find ugly the use of the aliasing type combined with a computation carried on by the *side effects* of the expanded pack (with the nasty `Int` hack on top). I find difficult to read that code, so I may have read it wrong. Why not [using the straightforward approach?](https://godbolt.org/g/vwC9fu) Due the impossibility to specialise functions directly?

Comment: @Antonio: Why are you creating an anonymous array of `int[]` and discarding it, instead of using `i &= ~(Int{1} << pos;` as your function body?  Am I missing some benefit, or is that just vastly over-complicated?

Comment: @PeterCordes That way you can write things like: write_one<1,3>(x); to clear bits 1 and 3 of x. I don't know if there is an easier way to write it. But maybe it's possible to do it another way.

Comment: @Surt I know that g++4.9.2 it's not the latest version, but it is the version that you can find with the toolchain of Microchip. (there is another version that uses g++ 5, but it is not the official one). And my question is about why the compiler treat differently write_one and write_zero??? Because the 2 functions are very similar but the compiler treats them differently.

Comment: If you really want to know, you could learn about gcc internals and look at the GIMPLE (gcc internal representation of your program logic), and see why they get optimized differently.  If I had to guess, though, it's because `~(Int{1} << pos))` has bits set outside the low 8 (because `int` is 16 bits on AVR, and C/C++ default integer promotion rules up-convert narrow integers to `int` before use in expressions).  You're not going to get anywhere reporting a missed optimization bug against g++4.9, because that branch is "closed".  If still present in gcc7 / gcc8, go for it, though.

Comment: Why does it manage to optimize for the simpler `PORTB &= ~(1 << PB0);` case?  I don't know, but maybe the truncation to down to 8-bit is applied more directly in the compiler's internal representation.  I also don't know how `PORTB` is defined, or what type that expression has.

Comment: Compilers have only "recently" begun to tell why they don't do certain optimizations, parallelising loops/vector operations(?). There must be some subtle difference between them that we cannot see but the compiler can, or some simple transformation that the compiler is not yet able to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<int... pos, class Int>
static constexpr void write_one(Int& i)
{
    using expand = int[];
    expand{0,((i |= (Int{1} << pos)), 0)...};
}
template<int... pos, class Int>
static constexpr void write_zero(Int& i)
{
    using expand = int[];
    expand{0,((i &= ~(Int{1} << pos)), 0)...};
}
I

Bit::write_one<PB0>(PORTB);
Bit::write_zero<PB0>(PORTB);

int[2] { 0, ((i |= (Int{1} << pos)), 0) }

int[2] { 0, 0 } // a tmp that is a nop
(i |= (Int{1} << pos))

(i |= (decl_type(PORTB){1} << int { PB0 }))
```

PORTB looks like it is an volatile uint5_t possible values 0-31 ([AVR](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_SBI.html)) with the value 0x5

```
(i |= ( uint5_t{1} << int {0}))
```

1 and 0 are literals/constexpr so it gives 1.

```
i |= 1
```

which code gens to

```
sbi 0x5, 0 // set port 5 bit 0


expand{0,((i &= ~(Int{1} << pos)), 0)...};
```

following the same logic gives

```
(i &= ~(1))
```

gives the code

```
d0: 85 b1           in  r24, 0x05   ; 5
d2: 90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0 <---------- this value is not used nor set any flags???
d4: 8e 7f           andi    r24, 0xFE   ; 254 (i &= ~(1))
d6: 85 b9           out 0x05, r24   ; 5
```

So the conclusion must be that there is an error in the code gen for AVR as it generates a spurious instruction.

explanaion of [ldi](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_ldi.html)

Comment: The spurious load is probably coming from `volatile`.  `i &= ~(1)` both reads and writes the volatile, and maybe gcc forgets that it's already reading the value?  Or maybe it somehow ends up with two volatile reads?  BTW, I think you tried to put a link inside your code block, because there's a literal `[ldi][2]`in the last one.

Comment: Oh I missed that was load-immediate.  Yeah that's super-weird and useless.  IDK if `volatile` explains that, it really just looks like a missed-optimization from gcc trying to optimize things back down from the very complex form in the source.